# Cefsharp RequestHandler can't catch all the incoming request

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I encountered a strange problem when using cefsharp. The browser accessed Twitter and automatically scrolled to the bottom to load new posts. There should be many requests, but the Function GetResourceRequestHandler didn't capture any requests, and the function wasn't called at all. Using the same class to capture Pinterest, requests can be captured, including XHR.

The link to visit Twitter is https://twitter.com/HanamuraAsuka
You can see many XHR requests in chrome's develop tool, such as https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/media/

I tried many times and the function was called for only a few times.

Thanks.

```
chrome.RequestHandler = New TwitterRequestHandler
```

```
Public Class TwitterRequestHandler

    Inherits RequestHandler

    Protected Overrides Function GetResourceRequestHandler(chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, request As IRequest, isNavigation As Boolean, isDownload As Boolean, requestInitiator As String, ByRef disableDefaultHandling As Boolean) As IResourceRequestHandler

        If request.Url.Contains("/timeline/media/") Or request.Url.Contains("/timeline/profile/") Then
            Return New TwitterResourceRequestHandler
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Don't need the 'Thanks'. Just the question.

Comment: Are you sure they are `XHR` requests? You cannot intercept `WebSocket` calls, everything else it theory should be captured. If you can reproduce the problem with the latest [CI Build](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#releases-1) then you should ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php `CefSharp` is just a `Chromium Embedded Framework(CEF)` wrapper.

Comment: @amaitland  yes I am sure. After add 'chrome.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new TwitterRequestContextHandler)'. the TwitterRequestHandler can capture all the requests. Confused, what's the connection between RequestContextHandler and RequestHandler

Comment: That's likely a bug in CEF.

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestContextHandler.html

Comment: @sdfew Hello, I have the same issue, can you share the browser initialization, RequestHandler and RequestContext code so I could see how you solved it?