# CefSharp responses not being detected when website is Cached

Tags: c#, vb.net, cefsharp

- CefSharp.WinForms
- Website in question is Twitter (I haven't observed this behaviour on
  other websites).
- I see all the network activity with Dev Tools normally.
- What I did (/and used to do for other sites) is implement
  IRequestHandler then get what I need via GetResourceRequestHandler.

*Now the issue*:

For some reason when twitter is cached only a single request appears this way or none (still see them normally in dev tools), if I delete the cache then I get a couple of dozen (same as dev tools).

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction (on how to get all requests/responses like in dev tools).

As far as the code goes just initialize browser with:

```
CEFBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1260339660892639233") With {
  .RequestHandler = New CefRequestHandler
}
```

and

```
Public Class CefRequestHandler
    Implements IRequestHandler

    Public Function GetResourceRequestHandler(chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, request As IRequest, isNavigation As Boolean, isDownload As Boolean, requestInitiator As String, ByRef disableDefaultHandling As Boolean) As IResourceRequestHandler Implements IRequestHandler.GetResourceRequestHandler
        Debug.Print(request.Url)
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

---

I also tried making another project to test [this out](https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2018/10/26/intercepting-ajax-requests-in-cefsharp-chrome-for-c/), but when that script is run the twitter doesn't load (also had a problem with the event handler conversion to vb.net but need to solve script blocking loading first anyway).

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/61577179/4583726

Comment: This should be reported on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: For background please read the first few paragraphs of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage